# FLEX/amfPHP ActionScript error 2048

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, amfphp, gateway

Sorry about the mishmash of words in the title, but that's how confused I am. I can't even summarize the error I'm getting in a simple sentence.

This flex/amfphp application works fine on my computer, even though it accesses an Oracle database on another server. However, when I try to access it from another computer, this is the error I get. I'll try and put the most relevant code in. (My browser tell me this is an ActionScript error).

Fault faultString="Send failed"

faultCode="Client.Error.MessageSend"

faultDetail="Channel.Security.Error error Error #2048: Security Area Violation..

Couldn't load data from http://localhost/.../amfphp/gateway.php

As I said before, it works on my machine for some reason. Now, when I try to access this remotely from other machines, it seems that the PHP engine is looking for gateway.php on the localhost of that machine?? Does this mean that PHP is looking for gateway.php on the client's localhost rather than on the server??

Correct me if I'm wrong, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your services-config.xml in Flex propably points to http://localhost/.../amfphp/gateway.php
You'll need to change the endpoint in that XML file and recompile the application.

You could also create your ChannelSet at runtime. In that case you don't need the services-config.xml anymore. Take a look at http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2008/06/05/endpointatruntime/ for some inspiration...